# Parse XML segment when elements may not always exist

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML string that I receive from an API containing status information. There can be different elements in the XML depending on whether the action was successful.

An example would be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content> 
<status>ok</status>
<response>ok</response>
<jobid>[integer]</jobid>
</content>
```

or possibly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content> 
<status>fail</status>
<error>missingdata</error>
</content>
```

I'm trying to use ElementTree to parse the XML data and pull out the values of each item, convert them to strings (if necessary), save to variables and write that data out to a log file.  The part that's throwing me is that I can't know for sure what elements will be there.

I've been using this link as guidance:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example that reads all existing elements from the xml data and stores them in a dictionary:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

xml1="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content> 
<status>ok</status>
<response>ok</response>
<jobid>[integer]</jobid>
</content>
"""

xml2="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content> 
<status>fail</status>
<error>missingdata</error>
</content>
"""

def get_elements(xml_input):
    ret = {}
    tree = et.fromstring(xml_input)

    for el in tree:
        ret[el.tag] = el.text

    return ret

print get_elements(xml1)
print get_elements(xml2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using try/except:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    try:
        x = child.find('response').text
    except AttributeError:
        continue
```

If there is a `response` element, x will give the value otherwise skip it. use this for all possible elements

Answer (score 0):

I suggest we create a simple class to parse the XML, turning all second-level nodes into object attributes. Then, we can check to see if the status is **ok** or **fail** and act accordingly. Here is a sample:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class XmlResponse(object):
    '''
    A simple class to parse a response XML
    '''

    def parseString(self, xml_string):
        '''
        Parses an XML block of text and convert all secondary nodes into 
        attributes for this object.
        '''
        root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
        for node in root:
            setattr(self, node.tag, node.text)

    def parse(self, filename):
        '''
        Parses an XML file and convert all secondary nodes into attributes for
        this object.
        '''
        with open(filename) as f:
            self.parseString(f.read())

def interpret_response(filename):
    '''
    A simple demo of how to use the XMLResponse class
    '''
    response = XmlResponse()
    response.parse(filename)

    if response.status == 'ok':
        print 'Job ID:', response.jobid
    else:
        print 'Error:', response.error

if __name__ == '__main__':
    interpret_response('ok.xml')
    interpret_response('fail.xml')
```

For the sake of simplicity, I don't check for error (such as file not found), but you should.